# Using apply on Stripe Node.js library functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

In my Node.js application I'm trying to use apply to make a function call in the Stripe library since the access token parameter is optional. However, I'm getting a type error.

```
var args = [data];
if(accessToken) {
    args.push(accessToken);
}
args.push(function(err, customer) {
    ...
});
stripe.customers.create.apply(this, args);
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'createUrlData' of undefined
  at /home/codio/workspace/node_modules/stripe/lib/StripeMethod.js:33:24
```

I believe this a result of using strict mode but let me know if this is expected behavior. I'm using version 2.8.0 of the Stripe Node.js library.

Comment: You probably don't need to jump though these hoops -- it's safe to just pass undefined in to the second parameter.  `stripe.customers.create(data, accessToken, function() { ... })`

Answer (score 0):

Likely your `this` is undefined, and `apply` sets the context (what `this` is) in the called function.  Under normal circumstances, the called function's `this` would be `stripe.customers`, so try:

```
stripe.customers.create.apply(stripe.customers, args);
```